# Laravel 8 and Vue Axios login not working

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, axios

I use Laravel 8, Vue and Axios. I use Laravel Modules, and I created Authentication Module. Register is good, but login doesn't do anything. I not use laravel/ui and auth. I don't know what is the problem.

**Login.vue**

```
methods: {
login() {
  if (this.username == "" || this.password == "") {
    this.errorMessage = "Tolts ki minden mezot";
  } else {
    axios
      .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/login", {
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password,
        remember: this.remember,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data == 1) {
          router.push({ name: "Dashboard" });
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
  }
},
```

**LoginController.php**

```
 public function login(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if (!Auth::attempt($request->only('username', 'password'), $request->remember)) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Authentication\Entities;

use Database\Factories\UserFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use HasFactory;
public $table = 'users';

protected $fillable = [
    'password',
    'username',
    'email',
    'firstname',
    'lastname',
    'birth'
];
```

}

**api.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function () {
Route::post('store', 'RegisterController@store');
Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login');
```

Comment: post your api route

Comment: Edited. But I think its good, because controller return true if I try to login.

Comment: what your getting `response.data` ? and session based login or token based ?

Comment: Response.data is true. Session based.

Comment: in laravel 8 the routes are defined in this way so `Route::post('store',[ RegisterController::class,store]);` and `
Route::post('login', [LoginController::class,login);`

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 8 the routes are defined in this way so `Route::post('store',[ RegisterController::class,store]);`

So try this

do not forgot to use
`use App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController;` `use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController;`

```
Route::prefix('user')->group(function () {

Route::post('store',[ RegisterController::class,store]);
Route::post('login', [LoginController::class,login);
```

}